# x86 Assembly Language: How to Interpret Value of CS Register

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, cpu-registers, xv6

Background info: I'm running Xv6 under QEMU, and using GDB for the debugger. I am stepping through the bootloader to see how it functions. Xv6 is designed to switch into 32-bit code before loading the kernel.

In the assembler file `bootasm.S`, the jump to 32-bit is made. The instruction that makes the transition is as follows:

```
# Complete transition to 32-bit protected mode by using long jmp
# to reload %cs and %eip.  The segment descriptors are set up with no
# translation, so that the mapping is still the identity mapping.
ljmp    $(SEG_KCODE<<3), $start32
```

The values of the segmented address' registers (composed of `CS` and `EIP` registers concatenated) right before the jump is made, as can be read from `GDB's info reg` command, is `CS=0x0:EIP=7c2c`.

Right after the jump, the segmented address is now `CS=0x8:EIP=0x7c31`, where `0x7c31` is the address of the beginning of 32-bit code (contained in bootasm.S under `start32`).
.

I know that the segmented address is turned into a physical address by multiplying `CS` by 16 and adding `EIP` to it as an offset. For example, when `CS = 0x0`, the physical address is `(0x10 * 0xf000) + 0x7c2c = 0xf0000 + 0x7c2c = 0xf7c2c`.

My question is regarding how the `CS` register is inherently valued. How does `CS` changing from `0x0` to `0x8` equate to running 32-bit code now? If I am understanding it right, based on how `0x0 * 16 = 0xf0000`, then `0x8 * 16 = 0xf0080`, right? But how does this segmented address equate to 32-bit? Or am I simply misunderstanding what the value of the `CS` register represents?

EDIT: Thanks to the responses, I realize that the `LGDT` instruction which is executed right before the jump is relevant. This is the instruction and its following instructions before the jump, as can be found in `bootasm.S`:

```
# Switch from real to protected mode.  Use a bootstrap GDT that makes
# virtual addresses map directly to physical addresses so that the
# effective memory map doesn't change during the transition.
lgdt    gdtdesc
movl    %cr0, %eax
orl     $CR0_PE, %eax
movl    %eax, %cr0
```

Comment: In this context `ljmp` the processor is in a quasi 16-bit protected mode (prior to this the PM bit in CR0 was set) without the _CS_ being set (still using cached values). *SEG_KCODE* is actually no longer a real mode segment but is a segment selector that is an index into the GDT that would have been set up prior to this _JMP_. Since _CS_ ended up being 8 that means SEG_KCODE is a value of 1. That implies the second descriptor in the GDT must have been defined as a 32-bit code segment and based on how the offset didn't change I can assume the base address of that descriptor is 0x00000000

Comment: Protected mode segmentation works differently than real-mode segmentation. Segment registers instead hold selector values, which are indexes into one of the two segment descriptor tables, the GDT and the LDT. A selector value of 8 is the second element in the GDT which should've been setup previously in the code with a LGDT instruction. The second entry in the GDT would have a descriptor for a 32-bit code segment.

Comment: That is correct, the assembler had run the `LGDT` instruction before the jump. I've edited my original question with that segment of the assembly code. Now my question is, if `SEG_KCODE` being 1 is the selected index in the `GDT`, then how does `CS` being 8 make `SEG_KCODE` to be 1?

Comment: With 32-bit Protected mode all the [GDT descriptor entries](http://wiki.osdev.org/GDT) are 64-bits (8 bytes). So the first descriptor in the GDT (NULL descriptor) starts at byte 0 of the GDT. The second descriptor is at offset 0x8, third at 0x10 (16-decimal). The index is effectively multiplied by 8. The lower 3 bits in this case are all zero. [That has meaning](http://wiki.osdev.org/LDT#How_are_LDTs_defined_and_accessed.3F) (a requested priv level of 0 and a for the table type means a GDT entry intstead of LDT)

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Why post your answer to my question as a comment, and not as an independent answer, so that I can mark this as solved and give you proper & deserved cred for it?